# Implementing localization testing with Appium automation framework

Tags: android, selenium, localization, automated-tests, appium

I'm working on an automation framework to automate a multi-language app. I'm thinking about creating json files which contains all the test data, and locators, and then call these data into my tests based on the language that I'm currently running the tests on. Does anyone have any tips that I can follow on how to implement that?